# Stripe Integration with Amazon pay in Alexa Custom Skill

Tags: stripe-payments, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-pay

I am creating a custom Alexa skill which accepts user payments through amazon pay. So user integrates there amazon pay with my skill to make the purchase. (https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-pay/amazon-pay-overview.html)

I am following this document, but there is no mention of connecting merchant account from the third party service like stripe. So my question is, is it possible to have a stripe merchant account instead of amazon merchant account and collect users payments (collected through amazon pay) in stripe instead of amazon merchant?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look into amazon pay closer.

Both stripe and amazon pay are so called "payment gateways".

They process the visa/mastercard or similar part of the card on your behalf and send you the payment (minus any fees). Money can not be transferred between them as it is two seperate companies and systems.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You'll need an Amazon Pay merchant account, which you can setup for free here: https://pay.amazon.com/signup